# Web audio API, problem using the panNode, the sounds only play once

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to integrate some panning effects to some sounds in a small testing app. It works fine except for one important issue: each sound only plays once!

I have tried several ways to attempt to bypass that issue without any success. The thing is, I can't pinpoint where the problem comes from. Here is my code, and a little explanation bellow.

```
const audio = new Audio('audio/background.mp3');
const footstep = new Audio('audio/footstep1.mp3');
const bumpWall1 = new Audio(`audio/bump-wall1.mp3`);
const bumpWall2 = new Audio(`audio/bump-wall2.mp3`);
const bumpWall3 = new Audio(`audio/bump-wall3.mp3`);
const bumpWall4 = new Audio(`audio/bump-wall4.mp3`);
const bumpWallArray = [bumpWall1, bumpWall2, bumpWall3, bumpWall4];

audio.volume = 0.5;

function play(sound, dir) {
  let audioContext = new AudioContext();
  let pre = document.querySelector('pre');
  let myScript = document.querySelector('script');

  let source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(sound);

  let panNode = audioContext.createStereoPanner();
  source.connect(panNode);
  panNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
  if (dir === "left") {
    panNode.pan.value = -0.8
  } else if (dir === "right") {
    panNode.pan.value = 0.8;
  } else {
    panNode.pan.value = 0;
  }
  sound.play();
}
```

So basically, when you call the play() function it plays the sound either on the left, the right, or the middle. But each sound is only played once. For example, if the footstep was played one time, it is never played again if I call the play() function on it.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Anything that prevents you from using AudioBuffers? That sounds a lot more natural for what you are doing.

Comment: I am not sure. I just learned about this yesterday so there is obviously a lot I don't know about. Would AudioBuffers solve the problem?
I will look into AudioBuffers than. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [developer console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console), you should have a message stating something along the lines of

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'createMediaElementSource' on 'AudioContext': HTMLMediaElement already connected previously to a different MediaElementSourceNode.

(At least in Chrome,) you can't connect a *MediaElement* several times to a *MediaElementSourceNode*.

To avoid this, you would have to *disconnect* this *MediaElement* from the *MediaElementSourceNode*, but [this isn't possible...](https://github.com/webAudio/web-audio-api/issues/1202)

The best in your situation is probably to use directly [AudioBuffers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) rather than *HTMLAudioElements*, moreover if you don't append them in the doc.

```js
let audio;
const sel = document.getElementById( 'sel' );
// create a single AudioContext, these are not small objects
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
fetch( 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/agepbh2agnduknz/camera.mp3' ).then( resp => resp.arrayBuffer() )
.then( buf => audioContext.decodeAudioData( buf ) )
.then( audioBuffer => audio = audioBuffer )
.then( () => sel.disabled = false )
.catch( console.error );

function play(sound, dir) {

  let source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = sound;
  
  let panNode = audioContext.createStereoPanner();
  source.connect( panNode );
  panNode.connect( audioContext.destination );
  if (dir === "left") {
    panNode.pan.value = -0.8
  } else if (dir === "right") {
    panNode.pan.value = 0.8;
  } else {
    panNode.pan.value = 0;
  }
  source.start( 0 );
  
}

sel.onchange = evt => play( audio, sel.value );
```

```html
<select id="sel" disabled>
  <option>left</option>
  <option>center</option>
  <option>right</option>
</select>
```

Comment: OK thank you so much! I will look into that, try to understand what's going on, implement it into my code, and come back here to accept this answer as soon as I manage to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Hey it works! Awesome. But I am not sure how I have to approach it with several sounds. I have tried it but there can only be 1 AudioContext.
I will try to extrapolate from that but anyway, you deserve the reward :) Thank you!

Comment: Prefetch all your assets and store somewhere your code can access it, personally I'd probably use  a dictionary or an Array to store them. Create only audioContext anyway. You can make yourself a preloader helper which would return the AudioBuffer from the url (basically the 5 lines at the top of my answer, but as a function.

Comment: OK got it! you can ```fetch``` as many sounds as you like! it works :) I'm so happy

Comment: Hey, just in case you are still there, I get the following error message in the console: ```ReferenceError: sel is not defined```
Not that it affects anything but do you know what this line does exactly? ```sel.disabled = false```

Comment: Oh sorry it's getting the <select> element by its id directly, I did add the declaration at the bottom only... edited